# AFNetworking 2.5 How to set value for forHTTPHeaderField

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking

How can i perform following operation in AFNetworking "2.5".
I wrote this code in older AFNetworking version:

```
-(void)login{

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            username.text,@"username",password.text,@"password",nil];

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient= [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"some_url"]]];

    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    [httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:@"Token"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"some_path" parameters:params];

    [request addValue:@"some_value" forHTTPHeaderField:@"some_field"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@"Response- %@", responseObject);
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Error- %@",error);
     }];
    [operation start];
}
```

Comment: There are lots of articles and Stack Overflow pages about migrating from AFNetworking 1 to 2. I suggest you take a look at them, because they answer your exact question.

Comment: Can you provide me such link?Because I have not found it yet.

Comment: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide

Comment: https://gavrix.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/migrating-from-afnetworking-1-x-to-afnetworking-2/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792044/how-to-migrate-afhttpclient-afnetworking-1-0-to-2-0

Comment: I think you didn't notice "2.5" mentioned in my question.All links you gave are related to "version 2.0".

Comment: The architecture is the same. Try one of those out. If it doesn't work, post a question with your specific problem.

Comment: The question remains same...how to set header field value in afnetworking   2.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what i did in AFNetworking 2.5.

```
-(void)login
{    
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        username.text,@"email",password.text,@"password",nil];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:some_value forHTTPHeaderField:@"some_field"];

    [manager POST:@"some_url" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) 
    {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } 
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
   }];
}
```